# WordPress WP Enqueue Script Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm experiencing a weird thing in WordPress about `wp_enqueue_script()`, what I want to happen is to add a script on the page by adding an action hook to functions.php but when I do, It doesn't add the script on the page but when I put the code as a plugin it now adds the script on the page

**NOTE:** in functions.php when I add the script in the footer: `add_action('wp_footer','function_name');` it works fine but when I add it on the wp_head and init it doesn't add the script when I put the code on the `functions.php`, but it works perfectly when I do it as a plugin even if I add it on wp_head and init

I NEED TO ADD THE SCRIPT ON THE INIT OR WP_HEAD BUT IT DOESN'T WORK WHEN I PLACE THE CODE ON FUNCTIONS.PHP I NEED THE SCRIPT TO BE PART OF THE THEME NOT AS A PLUGIN

```
//functions.php
add_action('init', 'function_name');

function function_name(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_holder', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js');   
}

//as a plugin
add_action('init', 'function_name');

function function_name() {
    $plugin_location=WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script_holder', $plugin_location . '/script.js');
    }
}
```

I know it should work even in functions.php but I'm really wondering why is this happening
can anyone help me and explain to me why is this happening, please?

thank you very much

**Basically This is Exactly What I'm doing:**

```
add_action('init', 'override_jquery');

function override_jquery() {
    if( !is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nashgraphics_jquery_library', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be several things going on, But since the problem occurs only with `functions.php` , One would think this is theme related .
You should be sure that the theme has both :

`wp_head()` – ( immediately before `</head>` )

And

`wp_footer()` – ( immediately before closing `</body>` )

If the theme author did not included both , or if the theme is missing even ONE of those functions , scripts might fail to load. ( and 80% of the plugins will have issues ) .

Also, you did not specify which theme you use (your own code ?? ) and if it is a child theme or not .

You are using `get_template_directory_uri()` which can not be overriden by child themes , I do not know if this is a part of the problem, but you might want to also try using ,  `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` which in many cases is the better choice .

Seeing your update :

It is a very bad practice to replace the core jQuery with another one withpout a fallback.
Anyhow ,you ca try dropping the !is_admin() condition, or alternatively log out and watch your sites code . ( I have a feeling that you are debugging it while logged in and with the wp admin bar on .. )

Comment: Yes I'm trying to create my own parent theme, it's really weird when I'm enqueueing scripts using add_action('init','function_name'); as a wordpress plugin it successfully includes the scripts but when I'm doing it in the functions.php it doesn't include the scripts

Comment: Did you read what I wrote ? Do you have wp_head() and wp_footer() ??

Comment: yep I have read your reply I have both wp_header() and wp_footer() in the right place, It should be inside !is_admin because the functionality is just for front-end and my other problem when I don't use !is_admin ruins my featured post image uploader so that's one of the reasons why I used !is_admin aside from the front end purpose

Answer (score 1):

The proper hook to enqueue scripts on the front end is `wp_enqueue_scripts`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: thanks for your response, yes I know that but I really need the answer to my question, because my concern is why does it include the script when I placed the code as a plugin and doesn't include the script when I put it on functions.php

Comment: `init` fires after all plugins are loaded. You could try hooking into `plugins_loaded`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded

Comment: didn't worked also, please read the edit above so you know what exactly I'm trying to do. thanks

Comment: Well, I tested your code on a local install (twentytwelve + code in functions.php), and it works.